# Is it possible to create a custom share sheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, share, ios-sharesheet, android-sharesheet

I want to build this custom share sheet shown in the screenshot depending on the apps that are on the mobile, could anyone tell me if it's possible?    [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVtPm.png)

i am currently using flutter's share_plus package, but the share method summons the platform's share sheet, is it possible to customize my own share sheet and use it for both platforms android and ios?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Flutter Availability](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability) package you can customize this by styling **BottomSheet** from scratch. Still, this package is only for Android devices. Unfortunately, iOS does not provide any API to get the installed APPs information.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You'll have to work with a modalBottomSheet and https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

You can check if an application is installed, but this would work only for android [Is there any way to identify that a particular application is installed in my android/ios device through flutter and dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141032/is-there-any-way-to-identify-that-a-particular-application-is-installed-in-my-an)