# Flutter Dynamic Links : PendingDynamicLink data is null

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

### Problem

I've been trying to set up deeplinking to my app via Firebase Dynamic Links and have used inputs from the following SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56986897/8129808) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58849538/8129808).

However, my app has Firebase Auth, so the way I have implemented identifying if there is a deeplink is by scanning in the 'Home' class (post auth) and then basing my code on the examples and from [this Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/if-you-want-to-make-your-product-popular-the-strategy-of-mouth-publicity-is-unavoidable-part-of-9da78ea32e79)

The issue is that the deeplink/dynamic link works in that the app is launched, but the data passed as parameters - the PendingDynamicLink data is null, and thus the parameters aren't picked up.

What am I missing here - any help would be much appreciated!

### The code where I generate the deeplink

```
Future<Uri> createDynamicLink({@required String docId}) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(

      uriPrefix: 'https://reviv.page.link',

      link: Uri.parse('https://reviv.page.link/doctor?docid=$docId'),

      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
          shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable),

      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'co.reviv.reviv_user.debug',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),

      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'co.reviv.reviv_user.debug',
        minimumVersion: '1',
        appStoreId: '',
      ),
    );

    final link = await parameters.buildUrl();

    final ShortDynamicLink shortenedLink =
        await DynamicLinkParameters.shortenUrl(
      link,
      DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
          shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.unguessable),
    );
    print("deeplink : " + shortenedLink.shortUrl.toString());
    return shortenedLink.shortUrl;
  }
```

### This is the code in my main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => LoadingIndicatorHelper()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => RevivUser()),
    ],
    child: CareProviderApp(),
  ));
}
```

### The CareProviderClass

```
class CareProviderApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData _revivTheme = _buildRevivTheme();

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Reviv Provider App",
      theme: _revivTheme,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/": (BuildContext context) => RootPage(auth: Auth()),
        "/home": (BuildContext context) =>
            MyHomePage(title: "Reviv Home", patient: null),
        "/login": (BuildContext context) => Login(title: "Reviv Sign In"),
        "/signup": (BuildContext context) =>
            SignupScreen(title: "Reviv Sign Up")
      },
      initialRoute: "/", //new rootpage.RootPage(auth: Auth())
    );
      }
}
```

### The Home Class

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  Patient patient;
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, @required this.patient}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {


  Timer _timerLink;

  List<Widget> _children;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks();
    // ... other stuff goes here
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }


  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _timerLink = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
        initDynamicLinks();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    if (_timerLink != null) {
      _timerLink.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void initDynamicLinks() async {
    print("checking for deeplinks");

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance
        .getInitialLink()
        .then((PendingDynamicLinkData data) {

      if (data == null) print("PendingDynamicLink data is null");

      final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {

        print("found deeplink");

        Doctor doctor;

        final queryParams = deepLink.queryParameters;

        if (queryParams.length > 0) {

          String doctorId = queryParams["docid"];

          print("Received deeplink pointing to doctor id: $doctorId");

          _docService.getDoctor(doctorId).then((Doctor _doctor) {
            doctor = _doctor;
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        DoctorDetail(doctor, widget.patient)));
          });
        }
      } else {
        print("no deeplink");
      }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 // .. yada yada
}
```

Here my output is always "PendingDynamicLink data is null". What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: check this answer, it may help. This worked for me: stackoverflow.com/a/67904367/6661043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the code snippet you've shared, it seems that you're fetching the Dynamic Link data inside MyHomePage. Calling `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInitialLink` to fetch `PendingDynamicLinkData` should be run on **main()** to be called during app start as mentioned on this [setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive#handle_deep_links).

Furthermore, there was an [announcement](https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq) that Firebase Dynamic Links will be shut down at some point in the future. So maybe you'd like to plan a migration soon.